# Creating custom metric descriptors continually results in HTTP 500

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I think I've broken my project's custom metrics.

Earlier yesterday, I was playing around with the cloud monitoring api, and I created a metric descriptor and added some time series data to it using the latest python3 cloud monitoring library `create_time_series` call. Satisfied with the results, I deleted the descriptor using the library, which threw an error as I had incorrectly passed in the descriptor's name. I called it again with the correct name, and it succeeded, but now every call to `create_time_series` on this project fails with an HTTP 500. The error message included simply says to "Try again in a few seconds," which I have, to no avail.

I have verified that I can create time series data on other projects of mine, and it works as expected. The API Explorer available in google's API documentation for metrics also gets an HTTP 500 back on calls to this project, but works fine on others. CURLing requests yields the same results.

My suspicion is that I erroneously deleted the `custom.googleapis.com` endpoint in its entirety, and that is why I am unable to create new metric descriptors/time series data. Is there a way to view the state of this endpoint, or recreate it?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to to delete the data stored in your Google Cloud project but deleting the metric descriptor renders the data inaccessible. Also, according to [data retention policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quota-policy#data_retention_policy), there is a deletion of this data when it expires.

To delete your custom metric descriptor, call the metricDescriptors.delete method. You can follow the steps in this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#deleting_metrics).

You are calling CreateMetricDescriptor every time when you call CreateTimeSeries. Some or all of these calls specify no metric labels, and these calls are therefore overwriting the metric descriptor with one that has no labels. The calls to ‘CreateTimeSeries’, on the other hand, do specify metric labels, causing the metric labels to be auto-added to the descriptor.

Custom metric names typically begin with      **custom.googleapis.com/**, which differs from the built-in metrics.

When you create a custom metric, you define a string identifier that represents the metric type. This string must be unique among the custom metrics in your Google Cloud project and it must use a prefix that marks the metric as a user-defined metric. For Monitoring, the allowable prefixes are **custom.googleapis.com/** and **external.googleapis.com/prometheus**. The prefix is followed by a name that describes what you are collecting. For details on the recommended way to name a custom metric, see [Naming conventions](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/naming-conventions).